# 100 custom cells displayed in tableView with UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a custom cell and i displayed that custom cell in a table view with method `numberOfRowsInSection` return `100`.

But when I edit one of the `textfield` it will reflect the changes in other textfields also.
this is my code for cellForROwAtIndexPath

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"viewAllProductsGridCell";

ViewAllProductsGridCell *cell = (ViewAllProductsGridCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewAllProductsGridCell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = gridCell;    

}
```

Will u pls tell me how to create multiple instances for each cell

Comment: Post code of method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same cell instance for all your rows.
You must create a separate cell instance for each row.

**Update:**

What I usually do for multiple custom cells is the following:

- Add an empty nib file to the project
- Set File's Owner to UIViewController
- Drag'n'drop UITableViewCell to the nib space
- Connect File's Owner view property with UITableViewCell instance
- Don't forget to set the ReuseID in the UITableViewCell properties to
  the predefined value (like textFieldCell)
- Customize your cell as much as you need by changing its properties
  or adding controls to it
- If you need complicated control over your custom cell, create a
  subclass from UITableViewCell in your project and add declare all
  IBOutlets or IBActions you need in it; don't forget to change the
  class property of your cell in nib to the MyTextFieldCell

When finished with customization, you can use the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"textFieldCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *theController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TextFieldCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (MyTextFieldCell *)[[theController.view retain] autorelease];
        [theController release];

        NSLog(@"Cell created %@", cell);
    }

    return cell;
}
```